# An attempt has been made to use a data extension that is either not registered for this report server or is not supported in this edition

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to implement Custom Data Extension for the SSRS reports to get data from an assembly code as DataSet and display them.

I am able to fetch data and create DataSet in RDL report but on preview it is displayin g the below error:-
[image: RDL Preview Error]

It seems like some mismatched version used.
Let you know my configurations as follows:-
Visual Studio 2013 with Data Tools 2014
SQL Server 2014 with MSDTBI tools and BI Services

Tried a lot but not getting any clue which all versions shall i use for VS and reporting services combination?

Any help would be of great help.

Regards,
Smruti Ranjan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar error to this. My issue was that I was using the wrong version of the Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces dependency in my data processing extension. I was retrieving it via NuGet rather than using the version that was included with my BI install located in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Microsoft.ReportingServices.Interfaces.dll`